# Java Processing: Rotate about a Point Using the Mouse

Tags: java, processing

I am creating a java processing program in which I need to rotate a rectangle about a point when the mouse is held down.

A few restrictions:

1. It can only rotate 180 degrees(in a semicircle)
2. Once it gets to the end of that 180 degrees, it must reverse the direction of its rotation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. My program is attached.

```java
void setup() {
    size(600, 600);
    smooth();
}

void draw() {
    background(0);
    noStroke();
    fill(169,169,169); 

    translate(width/2, height/2);

    boolean run=true;
    if (mousePressed==true && run==true){
        rotate(radians(frameCount/2));
    }
    if (mousePressed==false){
        run=false;
    }
    if(mousePressed==true  && run==false){
        run=true;
    }
    fill(255);
    rect(-50, -50, 50, 50);
}
```

Comment: Many of your methods are not shown. I'm afraid this is not a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and should be considered as off-topic for Stack Overflow because it needs more information.

Comment: @KnowNoTrend All is shown! That is the entire code! Read the tag info <[processing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/processing/info)>!. [Processing](https://processing.org/) is a flexible software sketchbook and a language for learning how to code within the context of the visual arts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3rd and 4th parameter of [`rect`](https://processing.org/reference/rect_.html) is not the bottom right point of the rectangle, it is its width and height.
If a rotation ([`rotate()`](https://processing.org/reference/rotate_.html)) is performed, then an object is rotated about its center.

You've to define a rectangle, with a center point of (0, 0). e.g.:

<s>`rect(-50, -50, 50, 50);`</s>

```java
rect(-25, -25, 50, 50);
```

---

If you want to rotate an object around a pivot (`poivot_x`, `poivot_y`), then you've to:

- Translate the object in that way, that the pivot is at (0, 0): `translate(-poivot_x, -poivot_y)`
- Then rotate the object: `rotate(...)`
- Finally translate the pivot back to its original place: `translate(poivot_x, poivot_y)`

Since matrix operations like [`rotate()`](https://processing.org/reference/rotate_.html), [`scale()`](https://processing.org/reference/scale_.html) and [`translate()`](https://processing.org/reference/translate_.html), define a matrix and multiply the current matrix by the new matrix, this operations have to be done in reverse order.

e.g. Rotate the rectangle (0, 0, 50, 50) around the center of the top edge (25, 0):

```java
int poivot_x = 25; // center
int poivot_y = 0;  // top

translate(poivot_x, poivot_y);
rotate(radians(frameCount/2));
translate(-poivot_x, -poivot_y);

rect(0, 0, 50, 50);
```